# Exploring the differences in proportions

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, proportion, association-measure

I have the following data:

| Score | Treatment 1 | Treatment 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| >=50% | 10 | 16 |
| < 50 % | 21 | 7 |

I need to describe the differences in the proportion of individuals with score <50% in the two treatment groups. How would I go about doing this?

I am trying to do this in R.
Would I need to run a chi-squared test or possibly the 3 measures of association (odds ratio, risk ratio, risk difference)?

I'm so confused...

** UPDATE**
I have tried the following in R:
`prop.test(21,31)` and `prop.test(7,23)`, is this the right thing to do? or would it be `prop.test(21,54)` and `prop.test(7,54)`?

Comment: It depends on what question you are trying to answer, right? If you just want to understand the difference in proportion of individuals, why not use a CI for the difference in proportions?

Comment: Thank you, and how would I go about doing this in R?

Comment: The output of `prop.test()` should contain it.